# Making sidebar thinner after rotating text inside of it

Tags: css

I'm trying to make clickable sidebar which already works fine but is way too wide which is most likely caused by rotated text. Here is a screenshot how it looks https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0Gf6.png

```
echo '<a class="patchlink" href="'.$patch_array[$x][$y].'"><div class="patch_big">'.$patch_array[$x][$y].'</div></a>';
```

here are styles

```
.patchlink{
    float: left;
    color: #626262;
    font-size: 80%;
    background-color: rgba(228, 228, 228, 0.84);
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.patchlink:hover{
    background-color: #A0A0A0;


}

.patch_big{
    float: left;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    margin: 20px 2px 2px 2px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a link or JSFiddle?

Comment: here you go http://89.69.172.125/LeagueNotes/Anivia this should work

Comment: Thanks, now are you trying to decrease the space in the grey rotated text box correct?

Comment: Yes and I would like it also to be the same width as in this example 3.14 patch

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. What is the 3.14 patch?

Comment: i mean 3.44 you can see it on that page is way thinner than the other ones so i want them all to be thin but the same width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I finally got it. Try replacing your current code with this. This should work.

```
.patchlink {
  color: #626262;
  font-size: 80%;
  width: 28px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(228, 228, 228, 0.84);
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.patch_big {
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-100%, 0);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```